# Dropdown lists in nested UpdatePanels

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, triggers, updatepanel

I am fairly new to this, and am using asp.net with Visual Studio. I have a system where people are going to download some data from a database. To do this, I would like to have two drop down lists. One for the zip code, and another for the MonitorID.

The zip code dropdown list is databound to show all of the distinct zip codes
The monitor id dropdown list is databound to show all of the monitor ids that are contained in the zip code from the first dropdown.

I would like to have the MonitorID list change depending on what is selected in the zip code list. I have read that UpdatePanels are a good way to do this. I have gone through forum posts, and feel like I am close to getting this working, but something just is not connecting properly, and I am not sure what. Below is my code:

```
<form id="rawDataForm" runat="server">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="RawDataScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
                </asp:ScriptManager>

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Outter_Zip" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListZip" runat="server" DataSourceID="DistinctZip" DataTextField="Zip" DataValueField="Zip" AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DistinctZip" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VOCMSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Zip] FROM [Monitor]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Inner_Monitor" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListMonitor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="MonitorFromZip" DataTextField="MonitorID" DataValueField="MonitorID">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MonitorFromZip" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VOCMSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [MonitorID] FROM [Monitor] WHERE ([Zip] = @Zip)">
                                    <SelectParameters>
                                        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="97601" FormField="DropDownListZip" Name="Zip" Type="String" />
                                    </SelectParameters>
                                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>

                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownListZip" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What other settings do I need to have set correctly? Anything to do with postbacks? I have a trigger on the Inner_Monitor update panel set to asyncpostback when the DropDownListZip selectedindex changes.

Comment: Hi, JClark4321 - did my answer help you out with your problem?  Or are you still stuck, and need some more assistance?

Answer (score 0):

I would say remove the inner UpdatePanel entirely:

```
<form id="rawDataForm" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="RawDataScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Outter_Zip" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListZip" runat="server" DataSourceID="DistinctZip" 
                DataTextField="Zip" DataValueField="Zip" AutoPostBack="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DistinctZip" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VOCMSConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Zip] FROM [Monitor]">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListMonitor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                DataSourceID="MonitorFromZip" DataTextField="MonitorID" DataValueField="MonitorID">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MonitorFromZip" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VOCMSConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [MonitorID] FROM [Monitor] WHERE ([Zip] = @Zip)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter DefaultValue="97601" ControlID="DropDownListZip" 
                        Name="Zip" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownListZip" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There's no need for it to be there - primarily because you would never need to refresh the inner UpdatePanel independently from the out UpdatePanel.

I also changed your FormParameter into a ControlParameter, because I think that's more useful in this scenario.